# How to get yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format from 28 Jul 2011 22:33:57 in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I have stuck in issue in which i have to convert date format is ***Thu, 28 Jul 2011 22:33:57 +0000*** into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
please give me some idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you have a NSString "Thu, 28 Jul 2011 22:33:57 +0000" and want to convert it to NSDate with format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"?

Comment: @dks did u find the anwer then post ur code . it will really helpfult to tothers.please

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, trying to do the same thing over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675839/rkvaluetransformers-failed-transformation-of-value-to-nsdate?noredirect=1#comment40162652_25675839

Answer (score 4):

What you want is to use the `NSDateFormatter`. Something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter* f = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString* dateString = [f stringFromDate:date];
```

Do note that the hours will still follow the users selected locale. Use `kk:mm:ss` to enforce a 24-hour time.

Answer (score 1):

what have you tried? it's difficult to answer questions like this...

first you have to parse the date into an NSDate, use an NSDateFormatter, the incoming format looks like POSIX date format so should be easy.

then you want to output to the format you specify with another NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an NSDateformatter to convert the first date to a string with the following syntax.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]]; //Put whatever date you want to convert
```

Then if you want the date as an NSDate and you have the string generated above just put the following code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString]; //String generated above
```

Comment: "yyyy-mm-dd" is "year-minutes-days", not what he wants.