# how to get date in the following format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have following code for converting string to NSDate,Right now I'm getting

```
2014-03-24 18:12:32 +0000
```

like this but i need like

> 2014-03-24 18:12:32

help me.

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter dateFromString:@"2014-03-24 18:12:32"]);
```

Comment: [This may Help You!!! refer this link]


: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6874451/2567363

Comment: i tried this way but no luck.

Comment: Dude there is nothing wrong in what you are getting. When ever you log an NSDate object answer will be like that(all the fields will be there date,time,zone difference..). Please try to understand date does not have any formate. You can format it through `NSDateFormatters` then formatted string will show you the expected result, but the date object still looks like that only\

Comment: He there, if you use "[formatter dateFromString:]" you will receive an instancetype of NSDate. For getting a NSString from a NSDate, refer to the following: [formatter stringFromDate:[NSdate date]] - is that what you are trying to achieve? :)

Comment: if you still have doubt format the date again using the same formatter, try to print the string. will looks the same. Dont be confused logging a NSDate object with formatted date string

Answer (score 0):

`DateFromString` return date so it WILL include the timezone offset. If you need the date without zone offset convert it back to string after parsing. So it give you the desired parts only.

Try like this:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2014-03-24 18:12:32"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate);
```

**Output:**

```
2014-04-07 11:34:06.035 TestDate[1160:70b] 2014-03-24 18:12:32
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
NSDateFormatter * format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"]];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];


NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:@"2014-03-24 18:12:32 +0000"];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];


NSLog(@"STRING DATE %@",[format stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score -3):

You see [this](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)
docs and you can set the dateformate.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Try to explain what OP has to do to get it running. (Though it's really easy, there are tons of questions on SO and everywhere else on the net).